# Pandas - Trying to save a set of files by reading it using Pandas but only the latest file gets saved

Tags: pandas

I am trying to read a set of txt files into Pandas as below. I see I am able to read them to a Dataframe however when I try to save the Dataframe it only saves the last file it read. However when I perform `print(df)` it prints all the records.

Given below is the code I am using:

```
files = '/users/user/files'
list = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    list.append(df)
    print(df)
    df.to_csv('file_saved_path')
```

Could anyone advice why is the last file only being saved to the csv file and now the entire list.

Expected output:

```
output1
output2
output3
```

Current output:

```
output1,output2,output3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
path = '/users/user/files'
for id in range(len(os.listdir(path))):
    file = os.listdir(path)[id]
    data = pd.read_csv(path+'/'+file, sep='\t')
    if id == 0:
        df1 = data
    else:
        data = pd.concat([df1, data], ignore_index=True)
data.to_csv('file_saved_path')
```

Answer (score 0):

First change variable name `list`, because code word in python (`builtin`), then for final `DataFrame` use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
files = '/users/user/files'
L = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    L.append(df)

bigdf = pd.concat(L, ignore_index=True)
bigdf.to_csv('file_saved_path')
```

Comment: thanks, could you please assist to have the data added one below the other rather than concat it across columns

Comment: do you think`bigdf = pd.concat(L, ignore_index=True, axis=1)` ?

Comment: sorry edited your post by mistake.. I have updated my initial post with the expected output and what the current output is

Comment: @scottmartin - So my solution should working nice, only necessary same columns names in each file.